# Unable to set value for property driver-class-name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to configure Spring Boot to use 2 data sources. I tried this configuration:

***application.properties:***

```
spring.production.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.production.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.warehouse.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_warehouse
spring.warehouse.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.warehouse.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

First datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.production.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "productionEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "productionTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextProductionDatasource {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties productionDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }   

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public DataSource productionDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionEntityManager") 
    public EntityManager productionEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionTransactionManager")    
    public PlatformTransactionManager productionTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor productionExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

second datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.warehouse.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "warehouseEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "warehouseTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextWarehouseDatasource {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "warehouseDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties warehouseDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse.datasource")
    public DataSource warehouseDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseEntityManager")  
    public EntityManager warehouseEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager warehouseTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor warehouseExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

But during the start time I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set value for property driver-class-name
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.setValue(JavaBeanBinder.java:349)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:96)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:79)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:452)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:570)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:556)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$400(Binder.java:513)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:450)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:391)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
        ... 132 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.setValue(JavaBeanBinder.java:346)
        ... 142 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:485)
```

I'm using Spring boot war deployed into Wildfly server with deployed mariadb-java-client-2.4.2.jar. It's working fine when I use single datasource configuration. But with second datasource I get exception.
Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: in gradle or maven do you import adapter?